# Intermittent SSL Failures Authenticating with Server Using ASIHTTPRequest and MKNetworkKit

Tags: ios, ssl, asihttprequest, mknetworkkit

I'm working on an iOS app and I'm having intermittent SSL failures when I try to access some of the APIs on our API server.  The failures don't happen all the time, but they happen enough to be a significant problem.  When an SSL failure occurs, the error code reported is errSSLCrypto, or "underlying cryptographic error" (-9809).  I mostly see these problems when the app attempts to login, but I sometimes see it when accessing other APIs.

The app was written using ASIHTTPRequest and here is the code to construct the login request:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *loginFormDataRequest = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:...];
loginFormDataRequest.timeOutSeconds = 30.0f; // Included in an attempt to fix timeout problems
loginFormDataRequest.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection = NO; // Included in an attempt to fix timeout problems
[loginFormDataRequest addPostValue:self.username forKey:@"username"];
[loginFormDataRequest addPostValue:self.password forKey:@"password"];
[loginFormDataRequest addPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"applogin"];
loginFormDataRequest.delegate = self;
[loginFormDataRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(didFinishLoginFormDataRequest:)];
[loginFormDataRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(didFailLoginFormDataRequest:)];
[loginFormDataRequest startAsynchronous];
```

Pretty straightforward.

I already updated ASIHTTPRequest in response to Apple's [Technical Note TN2287](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2287/_index.html) and that did not help.  Neither did setting the `validatesSecureCertificate` property to `NO`.

The encrypted connection to the server seems to check out okay.  Chrome says:

- Your connection to [the server] is encrypted with 256-bit encryption.
- The connection uses TLS 1.0.
- The connection is encrypted using CAMELLIA_256_CBC, with SHA1 for message authentication and DHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism.
- The connection is compressed with DEFLATE.

The server is being contacted on port 442 using https.  I also tried an implementation of this login code using MKNetworkKit and I still intermittently saw an SSL error so I don't think the problem is with ASIHTTPRequest.

I'm out of ideas, so I'd be grateful for any insight any one might have.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you resolved this problem ?